# How does S3 detect mime type when using presigned URLs?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my application, users can upload profile pic. The image is sent directly to S3 using presigned URLs.

Now, let's talk a bit about security.
Isn't it unsafe? Let's say someone renamed the file from `file.pdf` to `file.png`. Now browser thinks it is `png` file, because of the extension.

So, the question is: does S3 in any way, detect the mime type and can reject a file if its mime type is different from what we have specified it to be?

Answer (score 3):

It's the application's responsibility to provide the correct MIME type when uploading the object.  S3 does not do any interpretation of the payload.

Browsers should not interpret the file based on its extension, they should use only the MIME type from the `Content-Type` response header -- which S3 sets to whatever you specify when creating the object.

Comment: Does S3 take MIME from presign url call, or from PUT? Anyway I send Content-Type in both, and type is not set, or not always, strange.

Answer (score 0):

I think for save image we used putObject function and persigned url is for signed image path leave it its not a point here I think you need to check at your end the actually what type of file user upload if its acceptable file MIME type after that proceed for AWS. its save your application response time.